# Ruby, stripe and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

How can I incorporate this script in ruby form so stripe charge doesn't go through if doesn't create post.

now if I remove validations post is posted if charge goes through and if charge doesn't go through post is not posted.

as soon as I add validations and something is missing, by clicking on pay when charge is correct, validation stops to save post in database but charge is going still through.

Wive

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>


  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :phone_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :post %>
    <%= f.text_area :post %>
  </div>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="Good Luck"
          data-amount="500"
          data-locale="auto"></script>


<% end %>
```

post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_admin!, only: [:index]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def show

  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Your post was create'
    else
      render :new
    end

      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 150

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path


  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:name, :email, :phone_number, :post)
  end

end
```

post model

```
validates :name, :phone_number, :post, presence: true

  validates :email,
            presence: true,
            format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9a-z\-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}\z/}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include the `begin` and `end` with the `rescue` in your try/catch block or I don't believe it'll work properly:

```
begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

You may also want to confirm that `params[:stripeEmail]` and `params[:stripeToken]` actually contain (expected) things before you try to create the Customer.

Comment: The `def create` is, more or less, an implicit `begin` so you don't need an explicit `begin` if you want the `rescue` to apply to the whole method.

Comment: yes that thing didn't work. Do you have any other advice?

Comment: I don't want that stripe charge popup window open if validation is not passing.

Comment: @DeanGergorić Looks like you re-asked this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454454) and I think the answer over there is the correct one based on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your Stripe interaction inside the `if` block for `@post.save`. Something like this:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    # Amount in cents
    @amount = 150

    begin
      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => params[:stripeEmail],
        :source  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Your post was created.'
    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
```

Also, I need to comment on the fact that this doesn't really belong in the controller. I would build a class to handle the Stripe interaction.

That way, in your controller, you would have something like:

```
if @post.save
  begin
    MyStripeStuff.create_and_charge_customer({
       email: params[:stripeEmail],
       token: params[:stripeToken],
       amount: 150,
       currency: 'usd',
       description: 'Rails Stripe customer'
    })
    redirect_to @post, notice: 'Your post was created.'
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end
else
  render :new
end
```